# How to download an image from an URL to a local dir?

Tags: c++, http, download

I'm using C++ without .NET on Win32, how can I download an image over HTTP from a website without having to re-invent the wheel? Is there an API or library that provides a single function to do this?

http://mywebsite/file.imgext --> C:\path\to\dir\file.imgext

Comment: When most of the answers does not satisfy you, most probably the question is not asked properly. Check this before asking: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: What makes you think I'm rude? I'm just searching for an solution that doest make me re-invent the wheel. Writing 20 lines is reinventing the wheel, writing 6 lines isn't. You don't have to defend yourself... It's not my intention to be rude to you.

Comment: you commented out any reasonable answer, some with the argument you knew about it, or tried it. So, the question is not correct itself - as much information you put in the Q, as useful answers you'll get (check the link, worths a lot reading it).

Comment: Will read that link in my free time, still I do state that I do not want to re-invent the process of setting up a connection, communicating, downloading and then storing using a buffered stream writer.

Comment: @TomWijsman when you are not using .net libraries what do you expect? you will have to set up connection and do things a little more manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [cURLpp](http://curlpp.org/)

I havn't used it yet, but [example20](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/70-example-20) looks like it could solve your problem.

Comment: libcurl was tried first, resulting in crashes, unaware of a C++ version of it. Yes, it has the same style as the first code we had, doing it in 6 lines.

Comment: Why did it 'result in crashes'? With how commonly-used the library is, I'd assume the bug's on your side not theirs.

Comment: If you're using libcurl as a win32 DLL, you MUST use the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION if you set CURLOPT_WRITEDATA - or you will experience crashes. ==> Brings me back to re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Marked this answer as the solution as it requires 6 lines (by directly writing to an ofstream) and I suppose it works cross-platform as it's newer. :-)

Answer (score 8):

WinInet APIs are easier than you think

Here is a complete win32 console program.  Can be built with  with VS 2010 Express and down loading windows SDK to get WinInit.

---

```
// imaged.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
// Copy file from internet onto local file
//      Uses Wininet API
//    program takes 1 mandatory command line argument - URL string
//    it downloads ito the current directory, or whatever is passed
//    as the second parameter to DownloadURLImage.
//    optional parameter, the name of the file (excluding path), by default it uses the
//    filename from the URL string.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <WinInet.h>  // from SDK
#include "string.h"
//#include<TCHAR.H>
//#include "Tchar.h"
using namespace std ;

int convertURLtofname (TCHAR * szURL, TCHAR * szname )
// extract the filename from the URL 
{
    char aszfilename [100];
    HRESULT result;
    char achar[3], aszURL [100];
    size_t nchars, i, j;
    int fresult;

    fresult = 0;

    nchars= _tcslen(szURL);
    i= nchars -1;
    while ((i > 0) && (szURL[i] != '/') && (szURL[i] != '\\'))  {i--;}
    j= 0; i++;
    while (i < nchars) { szname [j++]= szURL[i++]; }
    szname[j]=_T('\0');

//  wcstombs ( aszfilename, szname, 100 );
//     cout << aszfilename << endl;
//----------------------------------------------
    return fresult ;
}

int determinepathfilename (TCHAR * szURL, TCHAR * szpath, TCHAR * szname, TCHAR * szpathfilename)
{  
// use path and filename when supplied.  If filename (e.g. funkypic.jpg) is not supplied, then the
// filename will be extracted from the last part of the URL
    int result ;
    result= 0;
    TCHAR szname_copy [100] ;

       if ((szname == NULL) || (szname[0] == '\0'))
            convertURLtofname (szURL, szname_copy);
       else
            _tcscpy (szname_copy, szname);

        if ((szpath == NULL) || (szpath[0] == '\0'))
                _tcscpy (szpathfilename, szname_copy);
        else
        {
            _tcscpy (szpathfilename, szpath);
            _tcscat (szpathfilename, szname_copy);
        }
    return result ;
}

bool GetFile (HINTERNET hOpen, // Handle from InternetOpen()
                    TCHAR *szURL,        // Full URL
                    TCHAR * szpath,
                    TCHAR * szname)   
{
    DWORD dwSize;
    TCHAR szHead[15];
    BYTE * szTemp[1024];
    HINTERNET  hConnect;
    FILE * pFile;
    TCHAR  szpathfilename [100] ;

    szHead[0] = '\0';

    if ( !(hConnect = InternetOpenUrl( hOpen, szURL, szHead, 15, INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0)))
    {
        std::cout << "Error: InternetOpenUrl" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    determinepathfilename (szURL, szpath, szname, szpathfilename);

    if  ( !(pFile = _tfopen (szpathfilename, _T("wb") ) ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error _tfopen" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    do
    {
        // Keep copying in 1024 bytes chunks, while file has any data left.
        // Note: bigger buffer will greatly improve performance.
        if (!InternetReadFile (hConnect, szTemp, 1024,  &dwSize) )
        {
            fclose (pFile);
            std::cerr << "Error InternetReadFile" << std::endl;
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!dwSize)
            break;  // Condition of dwSize=0 indicate EOF. Stop.
        else
            fwrite(szTemp, sizeof (BYTE), dwSize , pFile);
    }   // do
    while (TRUE);
    fflush (pFile);
    fclose (pFile);

    return TRUE;
}

int DownloadURLImage (TCHAR * szURL, TCHAR * szpath, TCHAR * szname)
{   int result ;

    HINTERNET hInternet;

    result= 0;

    hInternet= InternetOpen (_T("imaged"),
                                INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,  //__in  DWORD dwAccessType
                                NULL,                       //__in  LPCTSTR lpszProxyName,
                                NULL,                       //__in  LPCTSTR lpszProxyBypass,
                                NULL                        //_in   DWORD dwFlags
                            );

    GetFile (hInternet, szURL, szpath, szname) ; 
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return result ;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        DownloadURLImage (argv[1], NULL, NULL);
        //DownloadURLImage (argv[1], _T"C:/", NULL);
    }
    else if (argc == 3)
    {
        DownloadURLImage (argv[1], NULL, argv[2]);
        //DownloadURLImage (argv[1], _T"C:/", argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Usage: imaged <image URL>" << endl ;
    }
    system("pause") ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good example.  One correction seems to be needed in function GetFile().  BYTE *szTemp[1024]; should be BYTE szTemp[1024]; instead.  szTemp should be an array of bytes and not an array of byte pointers.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an EASY solution, use this amazingly simple one liner:

```
system("C:\\Path\\To\\Wget\\wget.exe http://pixelcaster.com/yosemite/webcams/ahwahnee2.jpg -O C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\ahwahnee2.jpg");
```

With wget for windows

```
choco install wget
```

See chocolatey.org

Answer (score 2):

Use [Windows Http Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: This requires me to open up a connection, communicate, download and write it to a file using a buffered stream. Doesn't there exist an easier way to do this? Other languages can do this using a single line.

Comment: Rude behavior invokes rude responses: use another language then.

Comment: Sorry, it's not my intention to sound rude. And yes, you're right about that. ^^

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331(VS.85).aspx) or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(VS.85).aspx) classes in C++. These are native Win32 APIs the abstract some of the work of getting sending and receiving files from the Internet.

I've used WinInet with great success to do just what you're trying to do.

Comment: This requires me to open up a connection, communicate, download and write it to a file using a buffered stream.

Comment: Here is some sample code from Microsoft on using WinInet for a FTP transfer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q238273/

Comment: Will keep it in mind if I need to write a client with FTP capabilities, thank you. Still this would require me to re-invent downloading a file over HTTP to my local hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

If starting a new process is ok, you could have a look at [WGET](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). (And even if not, the sources are available; you can look there to see how it's been implemented.)

Comment: Well, it is an quick solution but not efficient and it produces overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Using [POCO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poco/) for this now. :-)